# Applying Effects to HD Images

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that deals with images and applying filters, borders etc to the image..(like photo editing app).

I am facing issue when applying filters or borders to HD images (as images will be of different size and resolution).

My Question is how do I apply filters without changing the size or dimension of the Image. 
Please help regarding this, Thanks in advance.

As I mentioned in the comment section of the Code, for smaller size images getDrawingCache is returning a value, but for the bigger size images it is returning null.

```
public Bitmap getBorderAppliedBitmap(PorterShapeImageView imgView , GPUImage gpuImage)
{
    Bitmap bmp = gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imgView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    imgView.layout(0, 0,
            imgView.getMeasuredWidth(), imgView.getMeasuredHeight());
    imgView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgView.getDrawingCache());
 <!-- getting null from the method imgView.getDraingCache() only for the bigger size Images -->
    imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bmap;
}
```

Comment: Post some of your working code. Be specific with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you must be facing is limited Android resources issue for Image Processing techniques. The best advice for you would be to shift towards [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and write image filters in JNI using [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) .

It is the best option for faster results in HD images. Any how there must be a boundary to the resolution to which an image can be processed because all professional apps create their own boundary parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the thing is I just want to save the Image to external storage, not to display on the Screen. How it can be done ?

Comment: Why are you again getting the same image bitmap that you originally set into the ImageView why don't you just return bmp i.e. if it is the correct bitmap as you desire.

Comment: I have 2 images of different size, 
1st Image is normal image with lower dimensions, which is shown to the user, he can crop it, apply filters, fames etc.
What ever the effects applied to normal Image, the same should be applied to HD Image in background(here I facing the issue).
So while applying filters and frames I am facing the problem(i.e, getDrawingCache() returning null).